# add or move key and value to first position in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have the following array, we'll call it `$arr` and I have prepared a sample array. I need to manipulate the path `$arr['svg']` to have a specific key and value always at index 0 position. This is a sample data-set and depending on the data I'm working with the key's and values are not fixed, however the main point is to always have the **title array** (key and value) at the top of the svg array.

```
$arr = array("svg" => 
             array(
                 0 => array("@style" => "overflow:visible", "@xlink:href" => "test.png"),
                 1 => array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_2"),
                 2 => array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_3"),
                 3 => array("title" => "test")
             ),
             "@version" => 1.2,
             "@baseProfile" => "tiny-ps",
             "@id" => "Layer_1",
             "@xmlns" => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      );
```

I am trying to achieve two things under the array path $arr['svg']

1. If the array key **title** exists in $arr['svg'] and it is not in index 0 position
   then move it to index 0 of $arr['svg'] and shift everything else
   down.
2. If the array key **title** DOES NOT exist in $arr['svg'] then add it array('title' =>
   'test') to index 0 position of $arr['svg'] and shift
   everything else down.

The expected output of $arr will be like so:

```
Array
(
    [svg] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => test
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@style] => overflow:visible;
                    [@xlink:href] => test.png
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [g] => 
                    [@id] => Layer_2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [g] => 
                    [@id] => Layer_3
                )

        )

    [@version] => 1.2
    [@baseProfile] => tiny-ps
    [@id] => Layer_1
    [@xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
)
```

I am trying to use this function to achieve this but it seems this function only works from the root array position $arr, not within a specific path $arr['svg']. If it can be modified to work within a specific path that would hopefully solve the issue.

```
//source: https://gist.github.com/wpscholar/0deadce1bbfa4adb4e4c
function push_at_to_associative_array($array, $key, $new ){
    $keys  = array_keys( $array );
    $index = array_search( $key, $keys, true  );
    $pos   = false === $index ? count( $array ) : $index + 1;
        
    $array = array_slice($array, 0, $pos, true) + $new + array_slice($array, $pos, count($array) - 1, true);
    return $array;
}

Usage:

$title = array("title" => "test');
$arr = push_at_to_associative_array($arr, 'svg', $title);
```

Comment: Ok, so please show us the code you currently have written to try and achieve this

Comment: sure, ill add the function im trying to use, one moment

Comment: I am tempted to ask how you create this array in the first place, sounds like that would be the best place to make these changes

Comment: its from a xml (svg) to array conversion..

Comment: there was an error in the array sample snippet in my post, i just updated the snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

process the svg array into a new one setting `[0]` to the default title if we later find a title, replace `svg[0]['title']` with the found one, then finally replace the original `svg` part of the array with the new one.

```
$arr = [
    "svg" => 
        [
            ["@style" => "overflow:visible", "@xlink:href" => "test.png"],
            ["g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_2"],
            ["g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_3"],
            ["title" => "Fred"]
        ],
        "@version" => 1.2,
        "@baseProfile" => "tiny-ps",
        "@id" => "Layer_1",
        "@xmlns" => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
];

function push_at_to_associative_array(&$arr)
{
    $new_svg = [];
    foreach ($arr['svg'] as $key => $svg){
        if ( $key == 0){
            $new_svg[] = ['title'=>'test'];
        } 
        if ( !array_key_exists('title', $svg) ){
            $new_svg[] = $svg;
        } else {
            # amend title
            $new_svg[0]['title'] = $svg['title'];
        }
    }
    $arr['svg'] = $new_svg;
}

push_at_to_associative_array($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [svg] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Fred
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@style] => overflow:visible
                    [@xlink:href] => test.png
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [g] => 
                    [@id] => Layer_2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [g] => 
                    [@id] => Layer_3
                )

        )

    [@version] => 1.2
    [@baseProfile] => tiny-ps
    [@id] => Layer_1
    [@xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
)
```

And if you run it without a `title` in the array

```
$arr = [
    "svg" => 
        [
            ["@style" => "overflow:visible", "@xlink:href" => "test.png"],
            ["g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_2"],
            ["g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_3"]
        ],
        "@version" => 1.2,
        "@baseProfile" => "tiny-ps",
        "@id" => "Layer_1",
        "@xmlns" => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
];

function push_at_to_associative_array(&$arr)
{
    $new_svg = [];
    foreach ($arr['svg'] as $key => $svg){
        if ( $key == 0){
            $new_svg[] = ['title'=>'test'];
        } 
        if ( !array_key_exists('title', $svg) ){
            $new_svg[] = $svg;
        } else {
            # amend title
            $new_svg[0]['title'] = $svg['title'];
        }
    }
    $arr['svg'] = $new_svg;
}

push_at_to_associative_array($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [svg] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => test
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@style] => overflow:visible
                    [@xlink:href] => test.png
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [g] => 
                    [@id] => Layer_2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [g] => 
                    [@id] => Layer_3
                )

        )

    [@version] => 1.2
    [@baseProfile] => tiny-ps
    [@id] => Layer_1
    [@xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
)
```

Comment: can we put the solution as a function? keen on testing this also

Comment: Yea, thats no biggy

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to do something like this:

```
function fix_array( $array ) {
    
    $svg_title_index = array_key_first(
        array_filter( 
            $array['svg'], 
            fn($item) => isset($item['title']) 
        )
    );
    
    if (! $svg_title_index) {
        array_unshift($array['svg'], ['title' => 'test']);
    } elseif($svg_title_index > 0) {
        $value = $array['svg'][$svg_title_index];
        unset($array['svg'][$svg_title_index]);
        
        array_unshift($array['svg'], $value);
    }
    
    return $array;
}
```

---

```
/* CASE 1 - SVG EXISTS BUT IS NOT FIRST */
$array = [
    'svg' => [
        [
            '@style' => 'overflow:visible;',
            '@@xlink:href' => 'test.png'
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'some existing title',
        ],
    ],
    '@version' => '1.2',
    '@baseProfile' => 'tiny-ps',
    '@id' => 'Layer_1',
    '@xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
];

print_r(fix_array( $array ));
```

---

```
/* CASE 2 - SVG DOES NOT EXIST */

$array = [
    'svg' => [
        [
            '@style' => 'overflow:visible;',
            '@@xlink:href' => 'test.png'
        ]
    ],
    '@version' => '1.2',
    '@baseProfile' => 'tiny-ps',
    '@id' => 'Layer_1',
    '@xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
];

print_r(fix_array( $array ));
```

[You can see it in action here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b995c8c5d1110e3fc074381d017b82fe8154df44)

Comment: there was an error in the array sample snippet in my post, i updated the snippet above.

Comment: this code doesnt work, when the array is produced, the title key and value are not in position 0 within the path $arr['svg']..

Comment: @user3436467 I updated the code so that it also handles case 2 - when SVG is not in the initial array

Comment: in your first case you say title is not in the first position but the code snippet shows it is first

Comment: I don't know why, but from the OP I understood that you might have the "'svg" key missing.  Not the `title` within the `svg` array. My bad :). I updated the code and the sandbox example

Comment: seems better now except the result is showing "title" as the index and not 0             ```[title] => Array ( [title] => test)```

Comment: @user3436467 fixed that as well :) glad you found your solution in the other answer

Comment: thanks for your assistance. really appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so OP want's to move the array with the `title` attribute to the start of the array or insert a test value if it doesn't exist.

The below function should achieve this. It might not be the most beautiful or effient but it should put you on the right track.

```php
function order_svg_title( array $input, ?string $default_title ) {

  $position = null;

  // Find position of existing title (if exists).
  foreach( $input[ 'svg' ] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( isset( $value[ 'title' ] ) && $key !== 0 ) {
      $position = $key;
    }
  }

  // Doesn't already exist, add default title (if not null).
  if ( is_null( $position ) ) {
    array_unshift( $input[ 'svg' ], array( 'title' => $default_title ) );
  }

  // Title exists but it's in the wrong position.
  else {
    $value = $input[ 'svg' ][ $position ];
    unset( $input[ 'svg' ][ $position ] );
    array_unshift( $input[ 'svg' ], $value );
  }

  return $input;

}
```

So for this example usage would be...

```php
$arr = array(
   "svg" => array(
      array(
        "@style" => "overflow:visible",
        "@xlink:href" => "test.png"
      ),
      array(
        array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_2"),
        array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_3")
      )
   ),
  "@version" => 1.2,
  "@baseProfile" => "tiny-ps",
  "@id" => "Layer_1",
  "@xmlns" => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
);

$new_arr = order_svg_title( $arr, 'test' );
```

Would return:

```
Array
(
    [svg] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => test
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@style] => overflow:visible
                    [@xlink:href] => test.png
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [g] => 
                            [@id] => Layer_2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [g] => 
                            [@id] => Layer_3
                        )

                )

        )

    [@version] => 1.2
    [@baseProfile] => tiny-ps
    [@id] => Layer_1
    [@xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
)
```

Now with an existing title:

```php
$arr = array(
   "svg" => array(
      array(
        "@style" => "overflow:visible",
        "@xlink:href" => "test.png"
      ),
      array(
        array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_2"),
        array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_3")
      ),
      array(
        "title" => "In the wrong position. I should be moved."
      )
   ),
  "@version" => 1.2,
  "@baseProfile" => "tiny-ps",
  "@id" => "Layer_1",
  "@xmlns" => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
);

$new_arr = order_svg_title( $arr, 'test' );
```

Would return:

```
Array
(
    [svg] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => In the wrong position. I should be moved.
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@style] => overflow:visible
                    [@xlink:href] => test.png
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [g] => 
                            [@id] => Layer_2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [g] => 
                            [@id] => Layer_3
                        )

                )

        )

    [@version] => 1.2
    [@baseProfile] => tiny-ps
    [@id] => Layer_1
    [@xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
)
```

Comment: i realised i made a small error when i published the array sample data snippet in my post.. i have since updated it.. will the solution still work? i am going to test is now

Comment: this does seem to be working, just doing some additional testing.